# Google + Share getting error alert

Tags: iphone, ios, google-plus

I have to share some text on **Google plus** But it shows the alert, **There was a problem saving your post. please try again google plus.** I am using the [Google+ iOS SDK.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started.)

1) Whats wrong in my side?
2) How can I fix this alert?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not implemented sign in using Google+ then you have to implement [Google Plus sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in) first.
If you have already implemented then look at this code for sharing :

```
- (void)googlePlusShare
{
    [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

    // This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
    // item you're sharing.
    // thumbnailURL is url of image you want to display.
    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Title of your post"
               description:@"Description of your post"
               thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:www.example.com/image.png"]];

    /* This line passes the deepLinkID to our application
     if somebody opens the link on a supported mobile device */
    [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"share"];

    // set the text of post. user can edit this before sharing.
    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Your post texts."];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

This code uses `setTitle:description:thumbnailURL:` method to set details. 

If you have a web URL of your app then you can use below method instead of `setTitle:description:thumbnailURL:`.

```
[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/"]];
```

For more detail about Google+ sharing look at [Google Plus Sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share).

**EDIT :** I recommend you first check whether your `sign in` implementation works properly.

Comment: It is better if you post your code.

Comment: Thanks Akash. Still I am getting the same alert. But I don't know the reason of this issue.

Comment: @Mani Can you please post your code so that I can take a look? Also have you implemented Google+ Sign in and does that work correct?