# iOS Google+ App not returning back to app after user select Share or Cancel

Tags: iphone, ios6, google-plus, google-bigquery

I have an google+ api app the logs into google+ and share just fine but it doesn't return back to the app after posting or canceling the post i tried debugging it and it does not enter the - (void)finishedSharing:(BOOL)shared {

```
    - (IBAction)googlePlusPost:(id)sender {
    SLServiceTitle = @"Google+";


    /*[[[[share shareDialog] setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToShare]]
    setPrefillText:textToShare] open];*/

   [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
   id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

   // This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
   // item you're sharing.
   // thumbnailURL is url of image you want to display.
   [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Title of your post"
           description:@"Description of your post"
          thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToShare]];

   /* This line passes the deepLinkID to our application
   if somebody opens the link on a supported mobile device */
   [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"share"];

   // set the text of post. user can edit this before sharing.
   [shareBuilder setPrefillText:textToShare];

   [shareBuilder open];
   }
```

Comment: I have exactly the same. Any solution yet? If I do [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate] returning to the app does work. - edit:sorry I now see this was asked over a year ago and not last month.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in Google plus SDK. This is a link where the issue is opened:
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=794&can=8&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

I need to look into your code. Please post google+ related code. You can refer to my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018678/google-share-getting-error-alert/17018999#17018999).

Comment: the commented out part is what i had earlier and it didnt work i added what you recommended and it still didn't work

Comment: Have you implemented `GPPShareDelegate` in your .h file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first login in g+ then share video on g+ using native app dialog.

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
```

This will open native window in your own application.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/deep-link